# Impossible Java Memory Consistency Error

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, memory

first of all I'm not an English native speaker so I apologize for any eventual “weird” writing.

I'm developing a Swing Java application on Eclipse that updates a Jpanel. This panel contains several sub-panels, and I'm constantly switching the panels “modes”, what happens to be a MouseListener changing so they respond in a slightly different manner to the user mouse inputs.

Regardless of what the application do, it's happening an error that seems to have no logical explanation to me. At some point in my code I try to update the panels to what I called neutralMode. This happens on the following method:

```
//Guarded block (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)
private synchronized boolean waitsForUserSatisfactionAnswer()
{

    while(!userIndicatedSatisfaction) 
    {           
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    userIndicatedSatisfaction = false; //reset for future new query

    getObjectSetVisualizationPanel().neutralMode();
    //getObjectSetVisualizationPanel().queryPatternMode();


    return userSatisfied;
}
```

This updating doesn't work (the call to neutralMode() dont do what is expected). However the call to queryPatternMode() (commented on the line right below) works perfectly. So I decided to COPY queryPatternMode()'s body and PASTE it on neutralMode()'s body ECXATLY THE SAME! AND IT STILL DOESNT WORK!

The methods code is like this:

```
public void queryPatternMode()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside queryPatternMode!!!");
        System.out.println("panels.size(): " + panels.size());

        for (DigitalObjectPanel panel : panels) 
        {   
            System.out.println("Inside the loop!!!");
            panel.resetBehavior();
            panel.setQuerySelectionBehavior(gui);

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    panel.validate();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public void neutralMode()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside neutralMode!!!");
        System.out.println("panels.size(): " + panels.size());

        for (DigitalObjectPanel panel : panels) 
        {   
            System.out.println("Inside the loop!!!");
            panel.resetBehavior();
            panel.setQuerySelectionBehavior(gui);

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    panel.validate();
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

What happens is that, when I call neutralMode(), the “panels” collection happens to be empty (panels.size() equals zero). However when I call queryPatternMode() instead, the collection happens to have it's expected size (20 panels). But both methods are equals, and both are called from the same place!!!

What it could be??? Is there any possible explanation for that??

Comment: Do you do all your updating of Swing objects on the [Event Dispatch Thread?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: What is the scope of `panels`? Maybe you are hiding it in one method, but not the other? What does your IDE say? does replacing `panels`, with `this.panels` change anything? Do you have a complete functioning example we can try?

Comment: Your code looks to be possibly ignoring the principles of event-driven programming. Usually you shouldn't be continuously polling a variable such as `userIndicatedSatisfaction` but instead use a listener or observer pattern and thus be notified of changes. As recommended by others, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, I do all the ui update on EDT. panels is a private member, and both methods are from the same class panels belongs to. The IDE says nothing, there's no exception or errors at all, it's just on the application behavior. I just tried changing to this.panels and doesnt work...

Comment: That polling is a idiom called Guarded block, advised by the oracle java tutorials. After all, it seems to be working fine, the while condition checking is there to prevent some unexpected awake. The problem happens when I call the "mode" method. The specific method scope is defining panels visible size, what makes no sense at all!

Answer (score 1):

It definitely looks like a synchronisation issue. *You should check how many threads are accessing the collection 'panels'.*

It is just a stroke of luck that it works for you with queryPatternMode() all the time, and not with neutralMode(). On another fine day, it might be other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At first I also thought was a synchronisation issue, so I tried several fixes: 

-declared the panels list volatile 
-synchronized both methods
-changed panels access only to wrapper synchronized methods
-tried switching panels collection from arralist to vector
-tried getting panels through Collections.synchronizedList()

none of that worked. Besides, even taking thread issues into account, it doesnt really seems to make sense at all, since I'm calling the methods from the exact same point, and both execute the same code.

Comment: Also, there's some weird weird stuff happening: I tried to just delegate neutralMode() to queryPatternMode(), so I print panels size on neutralMode() and then call queryPatternMode() and print panels size again. And the collections size is still different! first zero and then 20! The method scope is the only thing defining the collections visible size!

Comment: One thing is for sure - it will not make any difference what you call those methods, so you can rule that out completely for sure. Forget about that, and carry on thinking about alternatives.
Again focus on where 'panels' is getting changed. Is it possible for you to share the full file here, or at least the methods where collection panels is being changed in any way?

Cheers